# Two big buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an app with JQM and PhoneGap for Android.

At the first page, I want two button with own images over the entire height

I've tried to use one  for both buttons. The  height of the div in css is 100%, but that doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Or another solution (even better):
The page is divided into two parts (both with height of 50%).
Part 1: includes one button with image 1
Part 2: includes another button with image 2
Problem: the images are very big, but I don't want to scroll the page

**CSS and HTML **

```css
#test {
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
}

#button1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin:auto;
}
#button2 {
  width: 70%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="content">
  <div id="test">
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="button1" href="#about"><br /><img src="images/about.png" class="image"/>about</a>
    <br />
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="button2" href="#product"><br /><img src="images/product.png" class="image"/>product</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'd suggest you to post your relevant code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CSS solution that mostly works.

> **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8zN6b/)**

Each button is in a DIV container and the button text is also in a DIV (i picked random 900x900 images from google image search):

```
<div data-role="content" id="contentdiv">
    <div class="btnContainer topBtn"> 
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="button1" href="#about">
            <img src="http://onlinelearningtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Mars-geology.jpg" class="image"/>
            <div class="thetext">about</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btnContainer btmBtn"> 
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="button2" href="#product">
            <img src="http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2004/11/11/0001201158/jupiterTriple_hst_full.jpg" class="image"/>
            <div class="thetext">product</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS then uses absolute positioning to make the content div fill the page and the 2 button divs take half the page each. Because the images are large, the CSS restrains the max-width and max-height and then centers them. The text is placed at the bottom of the button.  At smaller heights the text will appear over the images because percentages are used:

```
#contentdiv, .btnContainer a .ui-btn-inner, .btnContainer a .ui-btn-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.btnContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 50%;
}
.btnContainer a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;  bottom: 0; right: 0;
    margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;
}
.topBtn {  top: 0; }
.btmBtn {  bottom: 0; }

.thetext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 75%;
}
```

You can tweak the percentages, margins, etc. to get it closer to what you want...

UPDATE: to allow for a page header and or footer, play with the content div margin-top and margin-bottom:

```
#contentdiv{
    margin-top: 42px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Hi ezanker. That's my problem with your solution: http://s14.directupload.net/images/131212/4gx5w5cz.png

Comment: Well you did not say you had a page header, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8zN6b/2/. If the bottom is getting cut off, play with the #contentdiv margin-bottom.

Comment: One last problem: http://s1.directupload.net/images/131212/7dcaasdj.png
The images do not fit the size (height 100%). I do not want to scroll.

Comment: Do you mean the blue the button cutting off at the bottom of your uploaded png? When I visit the fiddle on a nexus, it seems to work correctly. Is yours opening in android chrome, or are you compiling to native app?  Did you play with the margin-bottom of the contentdiv? You can also try setting the bottom of the contentdive to a positive number e.g. 42px.

Comment: I'm compiling it to a native app. The main problem is solved, thanks for that. For the rest, I will try playing with the settings.

Comment: OK, good luck. If you find a mistake with my CSS, please post an update.